# What is wrong with my proof regarding division?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, fake-proofs

I wrote down $$12 \times 0 = 0$$ Then, I divided both sides by $0$ like so:
$$12 = \frac {0}{0}$$ I know that $$ \frac {0}{x} = 0, x \in R$$
Therefore, $$12=0$$ which is a false statement. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Both the "I divided both sides by $0$" and the $\frac 0x=0, x\in \Bbb R$ bits.  I suspect this is not a legit question though as generally everyone knows you can't divide by zero.  There's even a [meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/divide-by-zero) about it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. How should I prove, then, that I cannot divide by zero?

Comment: You don't really need to prove it -- division is only *defined* for nonzero numbers.  If you're really interested, you might like to note that division by zero can be defined in certain weird number systems.  Like on the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Riemann_sphere).  But even on that set of numbers, $\frac 00$ is undefined.

Comment: Why ask how to prove you cannot divide by zero? You didn't ask how to prove that $12\neq 0$, you merely accepted the notion that $12=0$ cannot be true.

Comment: *Proof by contradiction:* Assume you can divide by zero. That is to say, assume their is a multiplicative inverse for $0$.  If so then, $\exists (0^{-1})\in\Bbb R: 0\cdot 0^{-1}=1$ . However, zero is previously defined as the additive identity and, as such, : $\forall r\in\Bbb R:0\cdot r=0$ . This is a contradiction!  Hence you cannot divide by zero.

Comment: 12 = 0 is a definitely false statement, while by the definition of divisibility, 0|12 is defined as $12=0 \times b, b \in Z$. If I make the case that x approaches 0, then presumably there is a very small number b so that $12=0 \times b$.

Comment: $0$ is not and cannot be a factor of $12$ or any other number. (Please ignore the troll by the name Vytenis)

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. @GrahamKemp, your proof is interesting. Why am I able to assume that $0*0^{-1}=1$? Wouldn't it be $0* \frac {0}{0}$, which is $0$ since the $0$ and the denominator cancel out?

Comment: @manidy A (Dis)Proof by Contradiction is basically that: "If making an assumption can be show to entail a fallacy, then the assumption cannot be true." $$A\to C, \neg C ~\vdash~ \neg A$$

Comment: If you accept that $12=\frac00$, then $12=0$. Your proof has another non-standard definition in it, but _if_ $12=\frac00$ is true then it is possible to prove $12=0$ in other ways. Obviously we don't _want_ $12=0$, as it makes most mathematics basically meaningless, and that's one reason why the definition of division excludes division by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your proof. The first thing is when you divide by $0$ in your second line of work. Division by zero is an invalid operation. Then again you claim that $\frac{0}{x} =0$ when $x$ is a real number is also wrong. This is because in the real numbers $x$ can be zero and division by zero is an invalid operation. Overall both your second and third steps are incorrect because of division by zero.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot divide anything by 0. That is just not possible unless you want an undefined answer.